# `enquo` of column name variable not working with `dplyr::filter`

Tags: r, dplyr, quosure

Suppose we have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, odd=rep(c(T,F), 5))
```

And a variable that stores the name of the `odd` column:

```
odd_col <- 'odd'
```

**How do I use `odd_col` to reference the `odd` column in a `dplyr::filter` operation?**

From what I've read in [the documentation on Quoting in **dplyr**](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#quoting), I would think the following would be the correct approach:

```
library(dplyr)

odd_col <- enquo(odd_col)

# give the rows with odd entries
filter(df, !!odd_col)
```

but this results in an error:

> Error: Argument 2 filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector

However, this approach seems to work just fine with other **dplyr** operations, for example,

```
pull(df, !!odd_col)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: It works with pull, because pull does accept strings, i.e. `pull(df, 'odd')` works, but `filter(df, 'odd')` doesn't. So the problem is that you use enquo on a string and not the raw variable name.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sym` instead of `enquo` as it is a string

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, !!rlang::sym(odd_col))
# x  odd
#1 1 TRUE
#2 3 TRUE
#3 5 TRUE
#4 7 TRUE
#5 9 TRUE
```